# jquery drag item to canvas and drag it back to list

Tags: jquery, canvas, drag-and-drop

I'm using jquery to drag `<li>` item into canvas and its work fine.
But when i try to drag the item back to list, it does not work. Can you help me please?

Here is the [source](http://jsfiddle.net/BAZyF):

```
$("#group1").sortable({
    revert: true
});         


$('li[id^="item"]').draggable({
    // connectToSortable: "#group1",
     helper: function(){
        $copy = $(this).clone();
        return $copy;
     },
     start: function(event, ui) {
        dropped = false;
        $(this).addClass("hide");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if (dropped==true) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            dropped=false
            $(this).removeClass("hide");
        }
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#group1",
            //helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid"

        });
    }
});


var dropped = false;
$( "#canvas" ).droppable({              
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        dropped = true;
        $.ui.ddmanager.current.cancelHelperRemoval = true;
        //ui.helper.appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A canvas is just a chunk of pixels.  It is not a "container" element for other nodes.

If you look at the DOM tree more carefully in your code after dragging an element, you'll find they've not been added to the canvas at all.